# Merge diy and diy-3d-printer tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) and [diy-3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-3d-printer) - These seem *very* similar to me, but I may be wrong.

- [diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) has 7 questions
- [diy-3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-3d-printer) has 77 questions

All questions under [diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) could easily be tagged [diy-3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-3d-printer) and still make sense.

Merge [diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) into [diy-3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-3d-printer) or not? Delete [diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy)?

[diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) has no usage description anyway.

Comment: The merge seems logical to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have retagged all of the [diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) as [diy-3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-3d-printer) and removed the [diy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy).

In fact, 6 out of the 7 were already tagged [diy-3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy-3d-printer).